# who is going upload pom contents in nexus repo

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml

I have clarification uploading pom's in nexus repo. In one of the `pom.xml`, `parent` tag has mentioned where I see this pom resided in the nexus repo.

**Question**: Normally who is going to write this pom (`gts-component-super-pom-1.2.3.pom`) and uploaded into the nexus repo?

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.gts</groupId>
        <artifactId>gts-component-super-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
 </parent>
```

Available in my case at something lik:

```
http://xxx.xxx.info:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/company/gts/gts-component-super-pom/1.2.3/
```

Comment: the technical owner of the artifact (the pom), a CI job, a developer, each company has its own approach, but that is, an enterprise parent pom must be handle the same way as any transversal/shared component, with governance and care, and pushed to a Maven repository ideally from a CI job. Would that answer your question?

Comment: I don't have knowledge abt this parent pom & uploading into nexus repo. what is CI job?

Comment: CI stands for Continuous Integration, hence a Jenkins job is a CI job normally. So to narrow down the context: you are working on a project which has a parent company super pom, which is properly available in Nexus. Company or private project?